# Preferred scripts directory in python

Tags: python

I have the following directory structure in a windows environment

```
project
+-- scripts
    +-- const.py
    +-- ...
+-- unittest
    +-- ut01xxx.py
```

My PYTHONPATH is set to ..

ut01xxx.py reads

```
from scripts.const import *
```

When I run ut01xxx.py, it says

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts.const'
```

So I ran it with -v

```
python -v ut01xxx.py
```

In the trace, it says possible namespace for project/scripts but then it ignores that and picks the scripts directory from the python lib/site-packages/scripts.  I can get around that by

```
set PYTHONPATH to ../;../..
```

and changing the code to

```
from project.scripts.const import *
```

project is the top level svn checkout directory and the users can choose any name they like so this script will have to be modified whenever the user changes the project name.  Is there a better way other than renaming the scripts directory to something that doesn't exist in site-packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it

Option 1:

run with -S.

```
python -S ut01xxx.py
```

will disable the import of the module site.

Option 2:

Add __init__.py to scripts directory